# JPA join type for Embeddable and basic type

Tags: jpa, join, embeddable

JPA join: can join to Entity, Embeddable or basic type.

```
@Entity
public class Book {
   @Id String id;

   @Embedded
   Author author;

   String name;
}

Root<Book> root = criteriaQuery.from(Book.class);
root.join("author", JoinType.LEFT);
// or
root.join("author", JoinType.INNER);
root.join("name", JoinType.INNER);
```

From JPA api, it is legal to join to an Embeddable and Basic type, but what does  the JoinType mean? For inner join attribute "name", if book.name is null, the query will return empty results? the same for embeddable type?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misinterpreting the documentation.

A join can be used with `OneToOne`, `ManyToOne`, `OneToMany`, `ManyToMany` and `ElementCollection` mappings. This means the **target type** of a join may be an **entity** (when joining along entity associations), an **embeddable** (when joining to an `ElementCollection` of embeddables), or a **basic type** (when joining to an `ElementCollection` of basic types).

Nowhere does the above imply that it makes sense to use joins with a **singular attribute of a basic type**. JPA implementations might handle attempts to join to such attributes in a vendor specific way, though.

Comment: If an Embeddable type has an association, it must join the Embedded attribute first before join to the association. So it can join to a singular attribute of Embeddable type.

Comment: Not really. The only thing you need to do is navigate the path from the entity to the embedded attribute using `root.get()`. I'm guessing what you're really asking is how null values of the embedded attribute are handled. The answer is in JPA, an embedded attribute with null value is indistinguishable from a non-null embedded attribute filled with default values.

Comment: root.get("embeddedAttrName") return a Path instance, which can not Join to an association. Join source must be a From.

Comment: As you mentioned, the joinType for non-Entity may be just ignored. JPA spec does not say anything about it.

Comment: You are right, my bad. In any case, due to the null value semantics that I described above, the type of join does not matter for embedded attributes